# Unable to return value from service to controller for rendering in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, callback, promise

I have recently started using nodejs as I think I'm going to move onto a new project at work (I am usually a Java programmer).

I am making a rest service api.
Up until now I have had a routeing module which defines my endpoints and then a controller function is called which persists my object and then returns the response.

I want to delegate my persistence logic to a service module to keep it out of my controller. For my more complex cases this is definitely necessary.

I am struggling to find how I can successfully refactor my code to use a service. I have not so far successfully called a service method returning a value from my controller which is then rendered.

I will provide my original modules of concern that are working, followed by my failed attempt to pull out logic into a service module that returns a value:

routes/index.js

```js
const UserController = require('../controllers/userController');
const ProfileController = require('../controllers/profileController');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/api', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the Todos API!',
  }));

  app.get('/api/users', UserController.list);

  app.post('/api/users', UserController.create);

  app.get('/api/users/1/profile', function() {
    console.log('got profile for user 1');
  });

  app.post('/api/users/1/profile', ProfileController.create);
};
```

models/user.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};
```

original (working) controllers/userController.js

```js
const User = require('../models').User;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return User
      .create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
      })
      .then(user => res.status(201).send(user))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
  list(req, res) {
    return User
    .all()
    .then(users => res.status(200).send(users))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send("couldnt get list: " + error));
  },
};
```

Now I attempt to refactor and pull out the persistance code into a service:

modified controllers/userController.js

```js
const UserService = require('../services/userService');

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return Promise.resolve(UserService.create)
      .then(user => res.status(201).send(user))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
  list(req, res) {
    return User
    .all()
    .then(users => res.status(200).send(users))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send("couldnt get list: " + error));
  },
};
```

new services/userService.js

```js
const User = require('../models').User;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return User
      .create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
      })
  },
  list(req, res) {
    return User
    .all()
  },
};
```

I am fairly sure that my problem is my lack of knowledge about how callbacks and promises work.

Any help and/or advice would be really welcomed. 
I am trying to get a good head start with my re-skilling for my job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not calling `UserService.create`. Use `UserService.create()` instead (and drop the superfluous `Promise.resolve`).

Comment: yea, `.create(req,res)` should probably do it.

Comment: Or if you want to make certain that errors thrown by `create` are caught in the promise chain you could do: `Promise.resolve([req,res]).then(([req,res])=>UserService.create(req,res))`

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I have now got the list working and am now just getting the create part working. I had forgotten the parenthesis for my function calls.